# RxJs start an interval after a period of inactivity

Tags: websocket, rxjs, rxjs5

How can I emit a fixed value every `x` seconds ***after*** any `y` second-long period of inactivity on a stream?

---

In my app, I've got a RxJs wrapper around a WebSocket. This receives messages from both my client app and my API. There's a NGINX proxy sitting between the two that is configured to kill idle connections after 60 seconds. I already have retry logic implemented in my client code to try and re-establish a websocket connection if the connection drops, and that's working great. But it does mean that every 60 seconds I see a "Reconnecting..." message. I'd like to "ping" the server during periods of inactivity (ie, no messages sent from user actions or by the API) on an interval just shy of the NGINX timeout value. This should result in only seeing "Reconnecting..." when we have a legitimate connection failure.

Here's the observable code I have thus far:

```
const openSubject = new Subject()
const closeSubject = new Subject()

const socketStream = Observable.webSocket({
  url: socketUrl,
  openObserver: openSubject,
  closeObserver: closeSubject
})

socketStream
  .retryWhen(errors =>
    Observable.range(1, 15)
      .zip(errors, attempts => attempts)
      .mergeMap(attempts => {
        return Observable.timer(attempts * 1000)
      })
  )
  .merge(openSubject.mapTo(actions.socket.opened()))   
  .merge(closeSubject.mapTo(actions.socket.retrying()))
  .subscribe(dispatch, handleSocketError, handleSocketDone)

// messages from client are sent via
socketStream.next(/* ... */)
```

Ideally, if messages are being emitted on `socketStream` within the inactivity threshold, I should ***not*** see any emissions for my ping/keep-alive observable.

How can I accomplish this? I've tried various permutations of `switchMap`, `map().switch()`, and `race` and nothing I've come up with so far seems to work.